# Split string into words and punctuation but don't split on internal punctuation

Tags: java, string

I have a string `There is a boy's puppy. Really?`. I need to find external puncutation and split them out from the attached word and treat them as another word. The output would be:

- `boy's` would be one word (internal punctuation)
- `puppy.` would be two words, `puppy` and `.`
- `Really?` would be two words, `Really` and `?`

The code I have splits the words on the basis of external punctuation, but I want them as the separate word.

```
String[] Res = word.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What else do you think apart from ` ' ` as internal punctuation?

Comment: apostrophes that form contractions and hyphenated words

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase, i.e. `Res` should be `res`.

Comment: @user1631306 Got it. You can ignore apostrophes and hypens in the regex.

Comment: How about regex like this [^a-zA-Z0-9'] ?

Comment: @jker that will only work for most English text, but not for café or Grützwurst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do with your reg ex is using a non-capturing group so that it becomes part of the output, so in the reg ex I have two groups separated by an OR (`|`) where the first is capturing and the second one is non-capturing. I am not sure I've included all external punctuation you wanted in my non-capturing group, `(?=X)`.

```
String word = "There is a boy's puppy. Really?";
String[] res = word.split("(\\s+)|(?=[\\.\\?])");

for (String s: res ) {
    System.out.print("[" + s + "]");
}
```

Output is

> [There][is][a][boy's][puppy][.][Really][?]

Comment: What about other punctuation? Like `!:;[]()`. Or punctuation characters that could be either internal or external, like the `.` in abbreviations.

Comment: This answer may short-sightedly solve this particular question but fails miserably in teaching good regular expressions.`[.?]` is missing an explanation in the code and a rationale.

Comment: @mypetlion I did write in my text that the list of external punctuations was not complete, although I could have worded it better, and the reason was that the important part of my answer was the use of a non capturing group and not the exact list of characters to use.

Comment: @RolandIllig i don’t really understand your comment about missing an explanation and a rationale. I got the expression that OP was familiar with reg exp from the question so what level of explanation do you expect?

Comment: @mypetlion see the comment section regarding internal punctuation